# Parsing xml dynamic tag using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm a c# learner and now I've been facing this situation:

Here is the sample of xml I'm working on

```
<User_Security>
  <bob>
    <group>s1, a2, b3</group>
  </bob>
  <alice>
    <group>y3, c2</group>
  </alice>
</User_Security>
```

As you can see it uses the people as tag name not the tag data, so I cannot use getElementByTagName() by XmlDocument

How can I do to parse both name and the groups they belong?

Comment: There is no urgent, only ask.

Comment: Step 1: Get people who know how to give you decent XML.  The elements should not *be* the data; they should *contain* the data.  You can't validate this against a schema or anything.

Comment: It goes without saying that your XML design is not optimal.  The tag name should really be a `<person>`, with `name="bob"` as an attribute or an embedded element.

Comment: +1 to @cHao comment - Something like "O'Connor" would be nice as element name :)

Comment: I would use `XDocument` and then grab all of the children of `<User_Security>`. For each of the children I would grab the `<group>` node and then parse the inner text of that node. If it's guaranteed to be comma separated you might just do a `String.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim())`. It really depends on how robust and flexible you need this to be.

Comment: <bóbr></bóbr>? And you are f*ckd

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I know that this doesn't answer the exact question of how to solve the problem with your current XML; but as many people have commented, your XML is subject to malformation and will cause you a lot of problems. I've worked with XML far more than any sane person should be coerced into doing and the advice I offer will save you a lot of heartache.

Good luck!

What I would do is use attributes and maybe an XSD schema.

Make it like this

```
<User_Security>
    <user name="Bob">
        <group>c1</group>
        <group>c2</group>
        <group>c3</group>
    </user>
    <user name="Alice">
        <group>c1</group>
        <group>c2</group>
    </user>
</User_Security>
```

You can use a XSD to say that the file is allowed multiple groups in a user; I'll find an example and post it in an edit.

Edit:  An XSD fragment would look something like this, but you'll have to learn about the whole concept:

```
<xs:element name="user">
    <xs:attributename="name" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="group" type="xs:string" minoccurs="1" maxoccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

An alternate way to do this block would be:

```
<xs:element name="user">
    <xs:attributename="name" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:simpleType name="SKU">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

This lets you validate your XML input and ensure that your user node must use a name attribute and that it can have 1..many Groups which must be strings.

Comment: while this is a better format,  it really doesn't answer the question

Comment: While I think it's honestly fine if the OP just uses different xml, it'd be amusing to see something like: "Question: Is `P = NP`? Answer: You should really ask does `1 + 1 = 2`. The answer is yes"

Comment: @KeithNicholas I don't see your answer anywhere.

Comment: @I4V that's not even a logical comment.  you don't have to provide an answer to know that a given answer isn't answering the question

Comment: I know it's not an exact answer, but that's because I recognize the flaw in his question; that guy said he's learning so I gave him an answer to help his understanding a bit more.

Comment: @KeithNicholas But *"this is not the correct way, you should do it this way"* is also an answer (at least, future readers can get benefit of it).

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to deal with such XML - get child nodes of "User_Security" node and get node names :

- [XmlNode.ChildNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx)
- [XmlNode.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.name.aspx)

Sample from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx) article (adjust to your XML, may need to select root differently if "User_Security" is not top level element):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<book ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
            "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
            "<price>19.95</price>" +
            "</book>");

XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;

//Display the contents of the child nodes. 
if (root.HasChildNodes)
{
  for (int i=0; i<root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(root.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much more useful to restructure your XML as described by the 2nd poster.

With that structure, you could easily do something like this (nodRoot is the User_Security node):

```
foreach (XmlNode nodUser in nodRoot.ChildNodes)
{
   string userName = nodUser.Attributes["Name"].Value;
   foreach (XmlNode nodGroup in nodUser)
   {
      string groupName = nodGroup.InnerText;
      // do something with userName and groupName here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will parse out what you want...

```
        string xml = "<User_Security><bob><group>s1, a2, b3</group></bob><alice><group>y3, c2</group></alice></User_Security>";
        var e = XElement.Load(new XmlTextReader(xml, XmlNodeType.Element, null));

       var users = e.Elements()
        .Select(x => 
            new {
                Name = x.Name, 
                Groups = x.Element("group").Value.Split(new[] { ',' })
                         .Select(s => s.Trim())
                         .ToList() 
            }).ToList();


users.ForEach(u =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(u.Name);
        u.Groups.ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine(" - " + g));
    });
```

Comment: `that's not even a logical comment.you don't have to provide an answer to know that a given answer isn't answering the question` Seems something has changed in ~20 mins :)

Comment: @I4V Trying not to pull a white knight here but literally nothing has changed. Your comment _still_ just means "put your money where your mouth is" and does not speak at all about the validity of his original criticism. You can argue that he interpreted your comment incorrectly, but that's about it.